# pause gdb without breakpoint

Tags: c, gdb

When I am debugging a program in Xcode, I can pause execution in there debugger console.  Is there any way to do this using gdb from the command line?

I'd like to do this so I can modify breakpoints after the program has started.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614810/solaris-gdb-howto-pause-execution

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can just press Ctrl+C and will be able to do what you ask, although it might not always work (see comments below).

Comment: Ah, I thought this ended execution. So simple. :)

Comment: I don't know who gave me '-' but I would appreciate a comment if this solution is "wrong" in some way or if there are better ways. Thanks.

Comment: CTRL-C for me in MinGW *does* end execution. Is there a different way?

Comment: @Ben: Try Cygwin instead, I've used it (mostly) successfully for development on Windows while I have no internet connection (for my Linux dev VPS).

Comment: But it does not work in some cases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857300/gdb-ctrlc-doesnt-interrupt-process-as-it-usually-does