# gdb pause under NetBeans -- how?

Tags: c++, bash, netbeans, gdb, mingw

I'm having problems getting gdb to pause execution flow under NetBeans. The pause button doesn't appear to work at all. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614810/solaris-gdb-howto-pause-execution), I suspect it may be a problem with what text gdb is actually receiving as input (I'm under Windows/Mingw32 using IIRC msys bash). But this is just a guess.

I don't know where to view what is happening with gdb (input or output). I see a few mentions of it in the debugger console but not sure if that counts for anything. I'd post that log here but it is rather large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently a general problem with Windows/Netbeans, for which detail can be found on one of the NetBeans site pages (can't remember which).